# Does Salesforce Support SAML Artifact Resolution Profile

Tags: saml

I am using Salesforce as both the IdP and the SP. So, to be more secure I would prefer to use the SAML Artifact Resolution Profile instead of the Web Browser SSO Profile.  Since I cannot find any documentation that describes how to implement the Artifact Resolution Profile in Salesforce, I am believing that Salesforce does not support it.  If you know differently, please post a link to the implementation document.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what part of the spec makes you think that artifact is more secure?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce only supports two types of SAML 2.0 Bindings currently:

- HTTP Redirect (GET) Binding
- HTTP POST Binding

It is configured within Salesforce under:

Setup > Security Controls > Single Sign-on Settings > Service Provider Initiated Request Binding

[image]

---

Partially related but probably not helpful in this instance, ExactTarget (Salesforce Marketing Cloud) supports Artifact binding for SAML 2.0. [Documentation: ExactTarget SSO](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/admin/single_sign_on_authentication_via_saml_20/)